# php network connection not responding

Tags: php, sockets, iis, networking, iis-6

I have a php script that establishes a connection with a client server and validates transaction record. For some reason it keeps failing on our server, though runs successfully from my localhost.

My php code is pretty simple:

```
<?php
    $header = "POST /license HTTP/1.0\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($query) . "\r\n\r\n";       
    $fp = fsockopen($url, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 

    if (!$fp) { connection failure...}
    else {check response}
?>
```

It works perfectly on my localhost, but on our iis server, I keep getting:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

As far as I can see, the only difference is in the response header where our web server has:
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

and my localhost is:
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.10 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1b X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10

Our web server does have php (and we have other php scripts that run successfully too) and open ssl enabled (though I'm not using it for fsockopen).

Help please!

Comment: firewall blocking connection? do you have iptables or something else

Comment: show us the db connection function you are using

Comment: @Dagon, there is no DB being used yet, that cannot be the problem